# How to obtain the name of a caller from the phone number in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working in Android and I would like to know how to find out the contact name of a phone number.

In the `BroadcastReceiver` I have this:

```
String phonenr=intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

I need the contact name ( full name - firstname + familyname , if there is) for this phone number.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.html)

```
 Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
     resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME} .....)
```

Use the function Below like this:

```
  Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("your receive phone number"));
  Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME},null,null,null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            //it returns contact name
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
```

Comment: and the phoneNumber is in my case phonenr? where is the contact name retained?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [Retrieving Contact Information](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/retrieving-contact-information-name-number-and-profile-picture/)

```
 //query for the people in your address book
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,People.NAME + " ASC");
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    //bind the name and the number fields
    String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };
    SimpleContactAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleContactAdapter(this, R.layout.list_entry, cursor, columns, to);
    this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: i don't want to bind anything. i just want to print the contact name based on the phone number using a toast message. could you please update your code based on my needs?